# ImportError: cannot import name 'StanfordCoreNLPParser'

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I've been trying to extract subject-predicate-object triples from sentences and found this [awesome API](https://github.com/tdpetrou/RDF-Triple-API) that did just that. However, when it was written, it used the `StanfordParser` (`from nltk.parse import stanford, stanford.StanfordParser`), which is now defunct.

Instead, what is to be used now is the `StanfordCoreNLPParser`. Is this the right way to import it?

```
from nltk.parse.corenlp import StanfordCoreNLPParser
```

Anyways, I am trying to modify it `rdf_triple.py` file (found [here](https://github.com/tdpetrou/RDF-Triple-API/blob/master/rdf_triple.py)) to now use the new `StanfordCoreNLPParser`, while keeping all the functionality intact.

My code is below:

```
from nltk.parse import stanford
import os, sys
import operator
from nltk.parse.corenlp import StanfordCoreNLPParser
# java_path = r"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe"
# os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER'] = r'/path/stanford-parser-full-2018-02-27'
os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = r'/path/stanford-parser-full-2018-02-27'


# the RDF function starts here, the problems with the code are
# above this line, I think
class RDF_Triple():

    class RDF_SOP():

        def __init__(self, name, pos=''):
            self.name = name
            self.word = ''
            self.parent = ''
            self.grandparent = ''
            self.depth = ''
            self.predicate_list = []
            self.predicate_sibings = []
            self.pos = pos
            self.attr = []
            self.attr_trees = []


    def __init__(self, sentence):
        self.sentence = sentence
        self.clear_data()


    def clear_data(self):
        self.parser = nltk.parse.corenlp.StanfordCoreNLPParser(
                path_to_jar='/path/stanford-corenlp-3.9.1-models.jar',
                path_to_models_jar='/path/stanford-corenlp-3.9.1-models.jar')
        # UPDATE THIS PARSER!!!!
        self.first_NP = ''
        self.first_VP = ''
        self.parse_tree = None
        self.subject = RDF_Triple.RDF_SOP('subject')
        self.predicate = RDF_Triple.RDF_SOP('predicate', 'VB')
        self.Object = RDF_Triple.RDF_SOP('object')      


    def find_NP(self, t):
        try:
            t.label()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            # Now we know that t.node is defined
            if t.label() == 'NP':
                if self.first_NP == '': 
                    self.first_NP = t
            elif t.label() == 'VP':
                if self.first_VP == '':
                    self.first_VP = t
            for child in t:
                self.find_NP(child)


    def find_subject(self, t, parent=None, grandparent=None):
        if self.subject.word != '':
            return
        try:
            t.label()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            # Now we know that t.node is defined
            if t.label()[:2] == 'NN':
                if self.subject.word == '': 
                    self.subject.word = t.leaves()[0]
                    self.subject.pos = t.label()
                    self.subject.parent = parent
                    self.subject.grandparent = grandparent
            else:
                for child in t:
                    self.find_subject(child, parent=t, grandparent=parent)


    def find_predicate(self, t, parent=None, grandparent=None, depth=0):
        try:
            t.label()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            if t.label()[:2] == 'VB':
                self.predicate.predicate_list.append((t.leaves()[0], depth, parent, grandparent))

            for child in t:
                self.find_predicate(child, parent=t, grandparent=parent, depth=depth+1)


    def find_deepest_predicate(self):
        if not self.predicate.predicate_list:
            return '','','',''
        return max(self.predicate.predicate_list, key=operator.itemgetter(1))


    def extract_word_and_pos(self, t, depth=0, words=[]):
        try:
            t.label()
        except AttributeError:
#             print t
#             print 'error', t
            pass
        else:
            # Now we know that t.node is defined
            if t.height() == 2:
#                 self.word_pos_holder.append((t.label(), t.leaves()[0]))
                words.append((t.leaves()[0], t.label()))
            for child in t:
                self.extract_word_and_pos(child, depth+1, words)
        return words



    def print_tree(self, t, depth=0):
        try:
            t.label()
        except AttributeError:
            print(t)
#             print 'error', t
            pass
        else:
            # Now we know that t.node is defined
            print('(')#, t.label(), t.leaves()[0]
            for child in t:
                self.print_tree(child, depth+1)
            print(') ')


    def find_object(self):
        for t in self.predicate.parent:
            if self.Object.word == '':
                self.find_object_NP_PP(t, t.label(), self.predicate.parent, self.predicate.grandparent)


    def find_object_NP_PP(self, t, phrase_type, parent=None, grandparent=None):
        '''
        finds the object given its a NP or PP or ADJP
        '''
        if self.Object.word != '':
            return
        try:
            t.label()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            # Now we know that t.node is defined
            if t.label()[:2] == 'NN' and phrase_type in ['NP', 'PP']:
                if self.Object.word == '': 
                    self.Object.word = t.leaves()[0]
                    self.Object.pos = t.label()
                    self.Object.parent = parent
                    self.Object.grandparent = grandparent
            elif t.label()[:2] == 'JJ' and phrase_type == 'ADJP':
                if self.Object.word == '': 
                    self.Object.word = t.leaves()[0]
                    self.Object.pos = t.label()
                    self.Object.parent = parent
                    self.Object.grandparent = grandparent
            else:
                for child in t:
                    self.find_object_NP_PP(child, phrase_type, parent=t, grandparent=parent)


    def get_attributes(self, pos, sibling_tree, grandparent):
        rdf_type_attr = []
        if pos[:2] == 'JJ':
            for item in sibling_tree:
                if item.label()[:2] == 'RB':
                    rdf_type_attr.append((item.leaves()[0], item.label()))
        else:
            if pos[:2] == 'NN':
                for item in sibling_tree:
                    if item.label()[:2] in ['DT', 'PR', 'PO', 'JJ', 'CD']:
                        rdf_type_attr.append((item.leaves()[0], item.label()))
                    if item.label() in ['QP', 'NP']:
                        #append a tree
                        rdf_type_attr.append(item, item.label())
            elif pos[:2] == 'VB':
                for item in sibling_tree:
                    if item.label()[:2] == 'AD':
                        rdf_type_attr.append((item, item.label()))

        if grandparent:
            if pos[:2] in ['NN', 'JJ']:
                for uncle in grandparent:
                    if uncle.label() == 'PP':
                        rdf_type_attr.append((uncle, uncle.label()))
            elif pos[:2] == 'VB':
                for uncle in grandparent:
                    if uncle.label()[:2] == 'VB':
                        rdf_type_attr.append((uncle, uncle.label()))


        return self.attr_to_words(rdf_type_attr)


    def attr_to_words(self, attr):
        new_attr_words = []
        new_attr_trees = []
        for tup in attr:
            if type(tup[0]) != str:
                if tup[0].height() == 2:
                    new_attr_words.append((tup[0].leaves()[0], tup[0].label()))
                else:
#                     new_attr_words.extend(self.extract_word_and_pos(tup[0]))
                    new_attr_trees.append(tup[0].unicode_repr())
            else:
                new_attr_words.append(tup)
        return new_attr_words, new_attr_trees

    def jsonify_rdf(self):
        return {'sentence':self.sentence,
                'parse_tree':self.parse_tree.unicode_repr(),
         'predicate':{'word':self.predicate.word, 'POS':self.predicate.pos,
                      'Word Attributes':self.predicate.attr, 'Tree Attributes':self.predicate.attr_trees},
         'subject':{'word':self.subject.word, 'POS':self.subject.pos,
                      'Word Attributes':self.subject.attr, 'Tree Attributes':self.subject.attr_trees},
         'object':{'word':self.Object.word, 'POS':self.Object.pos,
                      'Word Attributes':self.Object.attr, 'Tree Attributes':self.Object.attr_trees},
         'rdf':[self.subject.word, self.predicate.word, self.Object.word]
         }


    def main(self):
        self.clear_data()
        self.parse_tree = self.parser.raw_parse(self.sentence)[0]
        self.find_NP(self.parse_tree)
        self.find_subject(self.first_NP)
        self.find_predicate(self.first_VP)
        if self.subject.word == '' and self.first_NP != '':
            self.subject.word = self.first_NP.leaves()[0]
        self.predicate.word, self.predicate.depth, self.predicate.parent, self.predicate.grandparent = self.find_deepest_predicate()
        self.find_object()
        self.subject.attr, self.subject.attr_trees = self.get_attributes(self.subject.pos, self.subject.parent, self.subject.grandparent)
        self.predicate.attr, self.predicate.attr_trees = self.get_attributes(self.predicate.pos, self.predicate.parent, self.predicate.grandparent)
        self.Object.attr, self.Object.attr_trees = self.get_attributes(self.Object.pos, self.Object.parent, self.Object.grandparent)
        self.answer = self.jsonify_rdf()


# =============================================================================
# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     try:
#         sentence = sys.argv[1]
#         sentence = 'A rare black squirrel has become a regular visitor to a suburban garden'
#     except IndexError:
#         print("Enter in your sentence")
#         sentence = 'A rare black squirrel has become a regular visitor to a suburban garden'
#         print("Heres an example")
#         print(sentence)
# 
#     # sentence = 'The boy dunked the basketball'
#     sentence = 'They also made the substance able to last longer in the bloodstream, which led to more stable blood sugar levels and less frequent injections.'
#     sentence = 'A rare black squirrel has become a regular visitor to a suburban garden'
#     rdf = RDF_Triple(sentence)
#     rdf.main()
# 
#     ans =  rdf.answer
#     print(ans)
# =============================================================================
```

What happens when I run my code is I get the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'StanfordCoreNLPParser'.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of anything called `StanfordCoreNLPParser`. The [`stanfordcorenlp`](https://github.com/Lynten/stanford-corenlp) package has `StanfordCoreNLP`:

```
from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
```

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name 'StanfordParser' from 'stanfordcorenlp' `

Comment: You are right. `stanfordcorenlp` has changed their API. I have updated my answer.